# EmberJS 2.15.1 Could not find module `fullcalendar`

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, fullcalendar, ember-cli

So I've recently updated my app to Ember 2.15.1 and I'm attempting to switch everything over to NPM from Bower.  I have been playing around trying to get fullcalendar to cooperate, but have not had much luck (last one to switch over too).  Figured it could have been a cache issue so both NPM/Bower cache and reinstalled NPM.  Below is the error and the code for importing it.

I have `import 'fullcalendar';` at the top of the calendar component.

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `fullcalendar` imported from `name/components/calendar`
    at missingModule (loader.js:247)
    at findModule (loader.js:258)
    at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
    at findModule (loader.js:262)
    at requireModule (loader.js:24)
    at Class._extractDefaultExport (index.js:389)
    at Class.resolveOther (index.js:109)
    at Class.superWrapper [as resolveOther] (ember-utils.js:423)
    at Class.resolve (resolver.js:164)
    at resolve (container.js:873)
```

When the import is removed I get a standard `fullCalendar is not a function` error.  Removing/adding `import $ from 'jquery';` does not change either of these.
Here's the part of the code it errors out on, though removing it just moves down to the next mention of fullCalendar.

```
 didInsertElement: function(){
      $('.sample-calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: '',
          center: '',
          right: 'title prev,next'
        },
        events: [],
        theme: true,
        aspectRatio: 0
      });
    },
```

The imports from ember-cli-build.

```
app.import('node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js');
app.import('node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css');
app.import('node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/plugins/gcal.min.js');
```

And then my package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~2.15.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.3.0",
    "ember-cli-datepicker": "wesm87/ember-datepicker#master",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "~3.5.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "~2.15.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-fetch": "3.4.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-moment": "~7.5.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-source": "~2.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "~4.1.2",
    "fullcalendar": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3",
    "pikaday": "~1.4.0",
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your third party library with import, ember needs vendor shim. you can check [here](https://ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies#standard-non-amd-asset)
simply run

```
ember generate vendor-shim fullcalendar
```

import vendor shim to your ember-cli-build and finally, import full calendar.
By the way, there is a wrapper for [full calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-fullcalendar).

Comment: I've used the vendor-shim for another module before (which I forgot to mention), but didn't have much luck with this one.  I'm assuming it might have been a difference in how they operate behind the scenes or our configuration.  Ended up going with the wrapper for now, which I was hoping to avoid as it doesn't seem to be getting any updates.  Definitely the easiest replacement for now though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ember component 'ember-fulcalendar':
https://github.com/scoutforpets/ember-fullcalendar/

It has the following in package.json:
"fullcalendar": "^3.6.0",
"fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.8.0"

You could switch to use the component or have a look at how the component does it.